# Dealing with big numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I am using Dev C++

the erratic line is...

```
long long n=600851475143;
```

**error description**:

```
integer constant is too long for "long" type
```

I need help in dealing with big numbers.

Comment: What compiler/OS/Memory Model are you using?

Answer (score 8):

```
long long n = 600851475143LL;
```

Appending `LL` makes it a `long long` literal. By the way, `long long` has not been standardized until C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Put an LL after it.

```
long long n=600851475143LL;
```

Comment: Do you mean `LL` rather than `L`? `L` makes it a `long`, and the error message that the original poster is getting would imply that the constant doesn't fit into a `long` type.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Whoops, yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Integer constants with no suffix get the smallest of `int` `long int` and `long long int` that can hold the value (2.14.2, Table 6), so, assuming that `long long` is needed for this value, `600851475413` has type `long long`. From the error message, it looks like the compiler is treating the constant as type `long` instead of `long long`. So adding `LL` is a workaround for a compiler bug.

Comment: As I understand it, that's a C++11 feature. For C++98, this isn't a bug.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - `long long` comes from C99, and C99 has the same requirement here. Regardless, supporting `long long` but not supporting implicit typing of integer constants is obviously a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your compiler(g++?) do not support long long type well, and numbers should be suffixed with LL, which is not supported in Visual C++. Try __int64 instead for n:

```
__int64 n=600851475143;
```

Both gcc and Visual C support __int64 on Windows.